# Style binding on (click) in Angular

Tags: angular, svg

I'm trying to make an interactive seats map where if you click on the seat it changes its color. I found some solutions but they're not working.

I have SVG element. I want the the black rectangle to change its color into red when clicked.

```
<g>
  <rect [style.color]="toggleColor()" (click)="toggleStyle = !toggleStyle;" id="2a" x="90.714" y="65.012" width="27.97" height="30.994"/>
</g>
```

The code in component is as below:

```
public toggleStyle: boolean = false;

toggleColor() {
  console.log("does it work?")
  if (this.toggleStyle) {
    return "red";
  } else {
    return "";
  }
}
```

}

As you can see on the stackblitz - this does not add the color to the rectangle. Additionally, the function runs twice due to the fact that it's part of the element.

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-txmbwn)

Thank you for any suggestions on how to fix this!

Comment: In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62486335/3744182) @qshyhoo writes, *After support this amazing community and own thinking this is the solution that's working and that I was looking for: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ang-stmp-hkx61z*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a seat selection, better way would be to define an array of object with `x`, `y` and `selected` properties. It can then be toggled directly in the template without using any event handler. Try the following

Controller

```js
export class ClickSVGComponent implements OnInit {
  public seats: Array<Array<{x: number, y: number, selected: boolean}>> = [];
  range = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

  public toggleStyle: boolean = false;

  constructor() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      this.seats[i] = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        this.seats[i].push({x: (i * 10), y: (j * 10), selected: false});
      }
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<svg width="210mm" height="297mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 210 297" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">

  <g>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let i of range">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let j of range">
        <rect 
          [attr.fill]="seats[i][j].selected ? 'red': ''"      <!-- use ternary operator to set the fill value -->
          id="{{i}}{{j}}a" 
          [attr.x]="seats[i][j].x" 
          [attr.y]="seats[i][j].y" 
          width="8" 
          height="8" 
          (click)="seats[i][j].selected = !seats[i][j].selected"
        />
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-u27jjw)

#### Update: max selection condition

I've changed the object structure to introduce a `maxSelected` boolean that denotes if the maximum no. of selections has been reached. To check for the condition multiple array `map`s and an array `concat` is applied in a `counter()` event handler for click event.

The quickest way to understand it would be to dissect the conditions and observe of the output of each statement. It is a fairly straight-forward condition written as a single statement.

The template is also adjusted for the condition. We need to allow re-selection if the `maxReached` is again set to `false`.

Controller

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export const MAX_SELECTION = 9;       // <-- max no. of seats allowed to select

interface Seats {       // <-- a collection of seats
  maxReached: boolean,
  attr: Array<Array<Attribute>>   // array of array - `x` denotes the row, `y` denotes the column
}

interface Attribute {    // <-- properties of each seat
  x: number,
  y: number,
  selected: boolean
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-click-svg',
  templateUrl: './click-svg.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./click-svg.component.css']
})
export class ClickSVGComponent implements OnInit {
  public seats: Seats = {maxReached: false, attr: []};
  range = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

  public toggleStyle: boolean = false;

  constructor() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {     // <-- loop through row of seats
      this.seats.attr[i] = [];         // <-- each row is initially empty
      for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {   // <-- loop through each seat of the row
        this.seats.attr[i].push({x: (i * 10), y: (j * 10), selected: false});
        //                          ^             ^           ^
        //                          |             |           |
        // use row value to set x ---             |           |
        // use column value to set y coord. -------           |
        // by default the seat is not selected ----------------
      }
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  counter() {
    /* 
    Do the following to understand what each statement does

    const seatsAll = this.seats.attr.map(row => { 
      console.log('row': row)
      row.map(seat => {
        console.log('seat': seat);
        seat.selected;
      })
    })
    console.log('all seats': seatsAll);
    const seatsSelectedConcat = [].concat.apply([], seatsAll);
    console.log('all seats single array': seatsSelectedConcat);
    const seatsSelectedTrue = seatsSelectedConcat.filter(status => status);
    console.log('all seats single array': seatsSelectedTrue);
    */

    const selected = (
      [].concat.apply([], (         // <-- output (Array(100)): [true, false, true, false, true,...]
        this.seats.attr.map(        // <-- output (Array<Array(10)>(10)): [[true, false...], [false, true,...], ...]  
          row => row.map(
            seat => seat.selected   // <-- output (Array(10)): [true, false, true...]  
          )
        )
      ))
    )
    .filter(status => status)       // <-- output only true: [true, true, true]
    .length;                        // <-- number of seats selected
    
    if (selected === MAX_SELECTION) {
      this.seats.maxReached = true;
    } else {
      this.seats.maxReached = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<p>
  Please select a maximum of 9 seats. <br>
  <span style="color: red" *ngIf="seats.maxReached">
    Maximum number of seats selected.
  </span>
</p>

<svg width="210mm" height="297mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 210 297" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">

  <g>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let i of range">        <!-- same loop as the controller - row -->
      <ng-container *ngFor="let j of range">      <!-- column -->
        <rect 
          [attr.fill]="seats.attr[i][j].selected ? 'red': ''" 
          id="{{i}}{{j}}a" 
          [attr.x]="seats.attr[i][j].x" 
          [attr.y]="seats.attr[i][j].y" 
          width="8" 
          height="8"
          (click)="
            seats.attr[i][j].selected ?           
              seats.attr[i][j].selected = !seats.attr[i][j].selected :     <!-- if seat selected already deselect it --> 
              !seats.maxReached ?
                seats.attr[i][j].selected = !seats.attr[i][j].selected :   <!-- selected unselected seat only if max condition `false` -->
                '';                                                        <!-- don't select the seat if max condition `true` -->
            counter()" 
        />
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Updated [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-seat-selection)

Comment: thank you very much for this broad answer! There is one element I did not mention earlier - maybe you'll be able to support here as well. The number of selected seats should be limited to 9 - should it be assigned to a separate variable and counted on click with i++ and then if it reached 9 there should be a break in the constructor? That's what comes first to my mind. Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Thank you very much for your amazing help! :) I'm having some problems to fully understand the logic behind some fragments of your code, especially this usage of "i" and "j" variables due to the point of knowledge I'm currently at. The task is part of final exam in my front-end post-graduate studies and for now I'm not sure I would be able to explain exactly what's going on there :) Do you think it would be possible for you to summarize the key steps in the process i.e. with comments in the code? I hope I'm not asking for too much.

Comment: @qshyhoo: I've edited the code to include some comments. Which university gives out postgrad degrees on frontend dev?

Comment: Thank you very much! The school is called Da Vinci and is located in Poznań, Poland. This is the link to the course: https://cdv.pl/studia-podyplomowe/poznan/biznesowe/it/frontend-developer/

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `fill` to change the color of an svg rect.

```
<rect [style.fill]="toggleColor()" (click)="toggleStyle = !toggleStyle;"></rect>
```

You can also use the attribute binding:

```
<rect [attr.fill]="toggleColor()" (click)="toggleStyle = !toggleStyle;"></rect>
```

Property binding does not work, because the attributes of svg are not reflected as properties on the element, so binding on svg happens with the `[attr.*]` notation

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-szecec?file=src/app/click-svg/click-svg.component.html)

You can also think about setting a property, instead of calling a function to get the current color. The reason it's calling the function twice, is because angular is running in development mode, and does two calls of change detection to make sure nothing changed after the first round

Comment: thank you very much, it solved the problem! And additional thanks for the extra details on this solution - it's really helpful. BTW: is this double function run something ok to be done or should it be avoided?

Comment: @qshyhoo the double function call is normal behavior, if you check your `main.ts` you see a `enableProdMode()` in an environment condition. Which means in a production build it will only run once, because it doesn't do the double check

Comment: One more thing - I see that if I add a second element with [style.fill] or [attr.fill] no matter which element I click, they both toggle. What may be the reason behind that?

Comment: @qshyhoo `toggleStyle` is a component wide variable, you should use a different variable for every element you may want to toggle

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying that. Do you think there is any solution to keep the code as simple as possible for this task? There will be at least 60 of rectangles to click and creating separate public variables for each of them may not be the best idea. This is for a post-graduate project and I want to make it with be best practice in mind. Thank you very much for finding time to answer my questions, your answers are really useful! :)

Comment: It depends how you are displaying the rectangles. For instance, if you are using `*ngFor` to show all the rectangles, you can either use the rectangle object to store a property in there, or have a selected array, and store the indices in that array, and query it to see if it's selected

Comment: They will be displayed in a form of SVG image similar to this: https://conceptdraw.com/a290c4/p1/preview/640/pict--aircraft-seat-map-airplane-seat-plan

Comment: @qshyhoo will it be a precompiled SVG, or are you building the svg inside angular? The basic idea though is that you need to get a reference somehow of every rectangle element, either by using the `ViewChildren` decorator or by some sort of data array inside your component. Then when clicking on one of these, you set a flag in an array that it is selected

Comment: It will be a precompiled SVG done in Inkscape and then the code will be pasted into HTML component.